# How to turn on antialiasing in rendering, using the Cycles render engine?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, edges, antialiasing

I have an option of anti aliasing for the 3D Viewport, but not for Cycles render output. I want antialiasing in my render too. The rendered image edge is aliased even when i am using high resolution.

This is my rendered image max zoom to see aliased edges. I use cycles to render.
I use anti aliasing node and denoising node.

[image: image with aliasing]

This is link of my blend file:

[image]

Comment: This is third time I see you asking the same question and I still don't understand what you want to know, what is jagged or pixelated? Render will be pixelated because it is rasterized and not vector based like in viewport... if you want more sharp edges you need more px*px image... what even is your render size? 1920*1080?

Comment: What I see here is some jpg artifacts.

Comment: That is expectable if it is jpg with compression, just saving it as png would solve that, but I am not sure if that is what he wants

Comment: i have tried saving in png and jpg both i mean aliased edges is my problem

Comment: you can view my file i have uploaded zoom to edges you will know my problem .I have the default resolution set in my file i even tried increasing resolution

Comment: Please do not repeatedly ask the same question across multiple posts. If you do not receive a satisfactory answer to your question, then please make an edit to your *first* question. See also [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) and the [tour] for more information on how to get more use from the site.

Comment: @KushagraKumarSingh The only way to smooth that is using the pixel Filter, this is inside the render setting >Film > Pixel Filter. in here you could switch from Black Man Harris to Gaussian and then play with the Width. Hope that helps

Comment: thx a lot it Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're talking about.

When CPU rendering the *Render Result* window displays some weird aliasing.

[image]

This is only present in the viewport, an exported image doesn't have this.

[image]

Comment: no it is also after exporting but it only comes when i zoom in an exported image.Can you pls more zoom the edges and see the pixalated edges of render the pixalated edges is also an another problem.This does not happen while creating or editing the object.

Comment: what you are saying is also a problem

Comment: help pls with my problem

Comment: @KushagraKumarSingh, I think many of us are struggling to understand what your problem is. That is why we have asked you to upload a rendered image that is "bad." We are not ignoring your question to be mean nor to be disrespectful, but we cannot understand the problem you are having. The cube image you have attached to this question looks fine to me, except for some JPEG artifacts?

Comment: i just want to Know how to turn on anti aliasing for my render

Comment: cause i am getting wired alised edges even when i am making the resolution too high

Comment: just help me turning on anti aliasing

Comment: see i am getting this type of edges https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN68B.png

Comment: i think anti aliasing will fix this

Comment: @Ron Jensen help

Comment: Save the image and then view it.  Does it look the same?  That's what I tried to say in my answer.

Comment: @ Allen Simpson exported image also has this but less if you zoom more you will be able to see . download my blend file and see.

Comment: @Allen Simpson help me turning on anti aliasing